# How do I apply moves (bitboard) and continue searching? My current attempt is throwing a strange error!

Tags: engines, programming, bitboard

### Explanation

I have a list of all possible current moves in a position. At each node, I want to then generate all possible moves and continue. The problem is that my code is modifying the list of moves in the node above. At least I think this is the case!

I am open to completely changing the way I handle moves, as I feel this isn't very efficient since I have a struct for every move.

### Output

This is the current output.

```
PS D:\Users\kmont\Desktop\ChessEngine> dotnet run
Number of moves at depth 1 is 4. It is White's turn.
Number of moves at depth 2 is 4. It is Black's turn. Previous move was knight to a3
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
    at Program.search(Int32 depth, Board board, String prevMove) in D:\Users\kmont\Desktop\ChessEngine\Main\main.cs:line 55
    at Program.search(Int32 depth, Board board, String prevMove) in D:\Users\kmont\Desktop\ChessEngine\Main\main.cs:line 60
    at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\kmont\Desktop\ChessEngine\Main\main.cs:line 33
```

### Code

The Move Struct:

```
public struct Move{
    public Piece.Type pieceType;
    public UInt64 piece;
    public UInt64 moveTo;
    public int color;

    public bool quiet;
    public UInt64 capturedPiece;
    public int capturedColor;
}
```

Search function:

```
public static void search(int depth, Board board, string prevMove = "nothing"){

    // If at the end of the tree, return.

    depth++;
    if (depth == maxDepth) return;

    Console.Write("Number of moves at depth {0} is {1}. It is {2}'s turn.", depth, board.allMoves.Count, board.color == 0 ? "White" : "Black");
    if (prevMove != "nothing") Console.WriteLine(" Previous move was knight to " + prevMove);
    else Console.WriteLine("");

    // Uncomment below line for a list of all possible moves.
    //if (true) foreach (Board.Move move in board.allMoves) Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    {0} {1} on square {2} can move to {3}.", move.color == 0 ? "White" : "Black", move.pieceType.ToString(), help.square(move.piece), help.square(move.moveTo)));

    foreach (Board.Move move in board.allMoves){
        Board newBoard = board;
        newBoard.color = 1 - board.color;
        initialiseBoard(newBoard);
        newBoard = makeMove(newBoard, move);
        search(depth, newBoard, help.square(move.moveTo));
    }
}
```

Make move function:

```
public static Board makeMove(Board board, Board.Move move){

    string moveColor = move.color == 0 ? "White" : "Black";
    string boardColor = board.color == 0 ? "White" : "Black";
    string pmove = help.square(move.moveTo);
    //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    Making {0} move {2}: It is {1}'s turn.", moveColor, boardColor, pmove));
    
    Board toReturn = board;
    // Remove piece from board
    if (toReturn.color == 0 & move.color == 0){
        if (move.pieceType == Piece.Type.Knight){
            toReturn.WhiteKnightsBitboard &= ~move.piece; // Get rid of piece on board
            toReturn.WhiteKnightsBitboard |= move.moveTo; // Add piece to board
        }
    }
    else if (toReturn.color == 1 & move.color == 1){
        if (move.pieceType == Piece.Type.Knight){
            toReturn.BlackKnightsBitboard &= ~move.piece;
            toReturn.BlackKnightsBitboard |= move.moveTo;
        }
    }

    Game.node++; // To count nodes
    return toReturn;

}
```

Initialise Board function:

```
static void initialiseBoard(Board board){
    BoardOperations.updatePieces(board); // Sets all pieces and finds empty squares 
    board.generateAttackSquares(board);  // Finds white knight moves and puts them into board.allMoves
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue may be here:

```
Board newBoard = board;
```

This creates a new variable, but it doesn't actually create a new `Board`. `board` and `newBoard` are pointing to the exact same `Board` object. So, when your code changes anything in `newBoard`, it also changes it in `board`, and when it changes, you get this error.

What you may want to do is make an actual copy of `board`, so when you change it, it doesn't change the original.

Comment: That's strange, but I can see how it makes sense. How would I make a copy? Would I have to start with `Board newBoard = new Board();` then copy over all components? Is there an easier way to do this? Is this efficient too? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much! I just made my own and this fixed the problem. I will look into performance soon!

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it, unless you have an easier way of making a new Board or there's already a built-in copy function. Also note that those components themselves may need to be copied, because the same thing might happen. `newBoard.someObject = board.someObject` would make `someObject` be literally the same object in both.

Comment: I don't know what the `Board` class looks like, but presumably you're going to want to add a `Copy` method to it, and you might be able to implement such a method like so: `public Board Copy() { return MemberwiseClone(); }`

Comment: alternatively you could add an `undoMove` function to put the board back the way it was.  You would call it after `search` in your for-loop.